# How to enable the flash player plugin in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, flash-player

I updated to IE8 the other day on my Vista laptop, mostly because Windows Update kept bugging me about it.  As a Chrome user, I don't really care so much about IE8, but I do have to use it occaisionally to test website compatibility.

At any rate, flash seems to be completely deactivated, and I don't see a place to re-enable it anywhere in the preferences.  I've done a bit of googling on the issue, but only found information about how to disable flash, not how to actually enable it.

I have the flash 10 debug player installed, and it works fine with Chrome and Firefox.  What could be the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you download the [Flash ActiveX](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) installer and try to install it again. I had a similar problem on a fresh install recently and it was the only way I could fix it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open "Tools > Manage Add-ons"
2. Make sure that for "Add-on Types" the "Toolbars and Extensions" option is selected.
3. Make sure that for "Show" the "Currently loaded add-ons" option is selected.
4. Select the "Shockwawe Flash Object" item, which you should see on the right side. Its details should now be displayed in the bottom half of the dialog, along with an  "Enable" button.
5. Click on the "Enable" button.
6. Click on "Close" to close the dialog.